# Woher stammt der „Weihnachtsmann“?

Tags: etymology, history, lyrics

Pünktlich zum Fest kommen meine Kinder aus der Schule und berichten, man habe ihnen im Religionsunterricht beigebracht, dass es den Weihnachtsmann gar nicht gäbe, sondern dass dieser von Coca Cola erfunden wurde.

Nun kennt man aber das Lied [„Morgen kommt der Weihnachtsmann“](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morgen_kommt_der_Weihnachtsmann), welches Hoffmann von Fallersleben bereits 1837 veröffentlichte, also lange bevor es Coca Cola gab. [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weihnachtsmann) meint, dass der „Weihnachtsmann“ auf dieses Lied zurückgehe, und auch im Grimms Wörterbuch heißt es:

> **Weihnachtsmann**, m. BERND deutsche sprache in Posen (1820) 35 setzt christkind in Posen und Westfalen gleich sonstigem nd. weihnachtsmann: das ist bisher das älteste zeugnis für das merkwürdig geschichtlose wort, vgl. zs. des sprachvereins 27, 1. in schwung gebracht hat es seit 1837 Hoffmann v. Fallersleben. <sup>[Grimms Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GW14066)</sup>

Auch das kann nicht sein, denn ich finde bereits 1809 im „[Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache](http://books.google.de/books?id=pJREAAAAcAAJ&dq=weihnachtsmann&pg=PA903#v=onepage&q=weihnachtsmann&f=false)“ von Joachim Heinrich Campe folgenden Eintrag zu „Ruprecht“:

> … und welcher besonders zur Weihnachtszeit den heiligen Krist oder **Weihnachtsmann** begleitet …

Die älteste Referenz, die ich gefunden habe, stammt aus dem Jahr 1771:

> Wenn der **Weyhnachtsmann** kömmt, will ich auch nicht hinsehen, daß mir das Christkindchen die Augen nicht auspusten kann. <sup>[Mannigfaltikkeiten. Zweeter Jahrgang, Berlin 1771](http://books.google.de/books?id=dBZJAAAAcAAJ&dq=weihnachtsmann&pg=PA259#v=onepage&q=weihnachtsmann&f=false)</sup>

Auch das klingt danach, dass bereits damals der Weihnachtsmann eine allgemein bekannte Figur war.

Gibt es irgendwelche Erkenntnisse, wo der Weihnachtsmann nun wirklich herstammt, oder in welcher Gegend er seine sprachlichen Wurzeln hat?

**Anmerkung:** Es ist wahrscheinlich thematisch verknüpft, aber es geht mir hier nicht so sehr um den Ursprung der Legende eines Geschenke bringenden Wesens (Christkind, Nikolaus, Santa Claus etc.), sondern schon hauptsächlich um die Herkunft des **Wortes** „Weihnachtsmann“.

Comment: Antwort auf die Frage aus dem Titel: Vom Nordpol.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Der Weihnachtsmann, so wie wir ihn heute kennen, hat eine lange Vorgeschichte und wurde durch Personen, Sagen, Mythen, geschichtliche Ereignisse und auch Firmen geprägt.
>
> Der Ursprung des Weihnachtsmannes geht auf den legendären Bischof
>   Nikolaus zurück, der im 4. Jahrhundert in der Stadt Myra in der
>   heutigen Türkei lebte. Dieser Bischof wurde durch seine besondere
>   Freigiebigkeit gegenüber den armen Leute bekannt. Es wird erzählt,
>   dass er einem armen Familievater Goldstücke gab , d.h. er warf sie
>   durchs Fenster, damit dieser seine Töchter verheiraten konnte. Vom
>   Nikolaus erhielt der Weihnachtsmann die Eigenschaft des Gaben- und
>   Geschenkebringens

Von [Santaclaus.de](http://www.santaclaus.de/main.php?I_ID=6&lang=de)

Unser heutiger Weihnachtsmann hat sich demnach aus dem Bischof von Myra entwickelt. Demnach halte ich es nicht für verwunderlich, dass du Quellen findest, in denen bereits im Jahr 1700 vom Weihnachtsmann berichtet wird.

Ich habe noch eine weitere Quelle gefunden, die die Herkunft des Weihnachtsmannes etwas ausführlicher beleuchtet:

> Die Figur des Weihnachtsmannes geht auf den heiligen Nikolaus zurück.
>   Nikolaus war im 4. Jahrhundert Bischof von Myra, einer kleinen Stadt
>   in Kleinasien, der heutigen Türkei. Er soll laut Überlieferung, als
>   Sohn reicher Eltern, sein gesamtes Vermögen unter den Armen verteilt
>   haben. Neben dieser historisch belegten Tatsache ranken sich um den
>   heiligen Nikolaus unzählige Legenden, die dazu führten, dass er einer
>   der wichtigsten christlichen Heiligen wurde. Angeblich bewahrte er
>   drei unschuldig zum Tode Verurteilte vor der Hinrichtung, stoppte eine
>   Hungersnot, rettete unzählige Seeleute aus Seenot und brachte es sogar
>   fertig, nach seinem eigenen Tod ein verschlepptes Kind seinen Eltern
>   zurückzubringen. Diese und viele weitere Legenden führten dazu, dass
>   Nikolaus nicht nur der Schutzpatron der Seefahrer, sondern auch der
>   Kinder, Händler und Ministranten ist und von unzähligen anderen
>   Bevölkerungsgruppen als Schutzheiliger verehrt wird. Ihm zu Ehren ist
>   der 6. Dezember ein kirchlicher Feiertag, für den sich im Laufe der
>   Jahrhunderte viele verschiedene Bräuche entwickelt haben. Der
>   Nikolaustag war ursprünglich auch der Tag der Weihnachtsbescherung und
>   ist es in einigen Ländern, wie beispielsweise den Niederlanden, auch
>   heute noch. Erst im Zuge der Reformation wurde die Bescherung auf den
>   24./25. Dezember gelegt. Das traditionelle Aussehen des Weihnachtsmannes war das eines Bischofs, entwickelte sich aber im
>   Laufe der 1920er Jahre mehr und mehr zu einem dicken Mann mit weißem
>   Bart und roter Kutte. Sämtliche Geschichten rund um den Weihnachtsmann
>   werden allerdings auch stark von regionalen Legenden und teilweise
>   heidnischen Traditionen geprägt. So wohnt beispielsweise der dänische
>   Weihnachtsmann in Grönland, der Finnische in Lappland und der
>   schweizer Weihnachtsmann im Schwarzwald. Auch ist der Rentier-gezogene
>   Schlitten nicht das einzige Transportmittel des Weihnachtsmannes. Je
>   nach regionaler Legende wird er ebenfalls von einem Esel begleitet
>   (Schweiz) oder kommt gar mit dem Dampfschiff aus Spanien angereist
>   (Niederlande).

Quelle: [extratip-goettingen.de](http://www.extratip-goettingen.de/fraeg-den-wissenschaeftler/woher-kommt-die-geschichte-vom-weihnaechtsmaenn.html)

Und noch eine dritte, die auf die Wandlung vom Nikolaus zum Weihnachtsmann eingeht.

> Der Weihnachtsmann ist eine Erfindung der Moderne. In früheren
>   Jahrhunderten brachte der Nikolaus den Kindern die Geschenke - und
>   zwar an seinem Gedenktag, dem 6. Dezember. Oft kam er nachts; dann
>   stellten die Kinder ihre Schuhe oder selbst gebastelte Schiffchen auf,
>   die sie am Morgen mit Äpfeln, Nüssen und Süßigkeiten gefüllt
>   vorzufinden hofften. Neben dieser anonymen Geschenke-Verteilung gab es
>   auch Einkehrbräuche: Der Nikolaus kam ins Haus, begleitet von seinem
>   Knecht Ruprecht (in Österreich dem "Krampus"), um festzustellen, ob
>   die Kinder brav gewesen waren und gut gelernt hatten. Historisches
>   Vorbild des Weihnachts-Nikolaus ist der Heilige Nikolaus, im 4.
>   Jahrhundert Bischof von Myra, der als Patron der Schüler gilt. Im
>   Weihnachtsbrauch wurde die Nikolausfigur dem entsprechend in
>   Bischofskleidung mit weitem Mantel und Mitra dargestellt. Der
>   Reformator Martin Luther wetterte heftig gegen solche
>   "Fastnachts-Narrheiten" und propagierte statt des katholischen
>   Heiligen einen neuen, protestantischen Gabenbringer: das Christkind.
>
> In der Folge löste das Christkind den Nikolaus ab, Geschenke gab es
>   jetzt am 24. oder 25. Dezember. Dessen ungeachtet bestand der
>   Nikolausbrauch weiter und wurde im 19. Jahrhundert zu einer neuen
>   Konkurrenz für das Christkind: Auf den alten Nikolausbildern
>   basierend, entstand die Vorstellung vom Weihnachtsmann. Zum ersten Mal
>   erwähnt wird er in dem Lied "Morgen kommt der Weihnachtsmann" von
>   Hoffmann von Fallersleben (1835); Moritz von Schwind zeichnete ihn
>   1847 als bärtigen Alten.

Quelle: [Planet-Wissen.de](http://www.planet-wissen.de/kultur_medien/brauchtum/weihnachtsbraeuche/wissensfrage_weihnachtsmann.jsp)

Comment: @Takkat du hast Recht. Deshalb habe ich meine Antwort um diesen Teil ergänzt.

Comment: Sehr schön, aber leider kann ich nur 1x upvoten ;) Auch Planet Wissen irrt übrigens was die erste Erwähnung angeht ;)

Comment: In früheren Jahrhunderten - damit ist wohl u.a. das 20. Jahrhundert gemeint. Selbstverständlich wurden in der Nacht auf den Niklaustag die Schuhe hingestellt, denn er kam nicht "oft" nachts, sondern immer und ausschließlich nachts.

Comment: Ich finde es spannend, dass so viele Leute die am Christkind festhalten und sich gegen den Weihnachtsmann als kommerzielles Wesen wehren, den Zusammenhang zwischen dem Nikolaus und Santa Claus nicht erkennen.

Answer (score 1):

Das hat nichts mit Deutschland oder Deutsch zu tun. Deshalb wirst du dir auch leichter tun, wenn du weiter rauf nach Skandinavien schaust. Die englische Wikipedia hat mich auf [Sinterklaas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinterklaas) gebracht, der der Ursprung zu sein scheint.

Das geht weiter als nur in das 17. Jahrhundert zurück. Allerdings ist der Weihnachtsmann in manchen Ländern, z.B. Österreich, tatsächlich erst mit amerikanischen Filmen gekommen.

In meiner Kindheit gab es nur das Christkind.

Comment: @Takkat Aber Weihnachtsmann und Nikolaus sind doch zwei Paar Schuhe.

Comment: @Em1: Hmmm, um die sehr passende Metapher weiterzuführen: eigentlich sind die beiden doch eher die Füße einer Strumpfhose, die im US-Santa sozusagen als Zwickel zusammenhängen. (Sorry, ich konnte nicht widerstehen)